# Inlining Functions

Tags: c#, inlining

What is inlining?

What is it used for?

Can you inline something in C#?

Comment: Also see this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**What it is**

In the terms of C and C++ you use the inline keyword to tell the compiler to call a routine without the overhead of pushing parameters onto the stack. The Function instead has it's machine code inserted into the function where it was called. This can create a significant increase in performance in certain scenarios.

**Dangers**

The speed benefits in using "inlining" decrease significantly as the size of the inline function increases. Overuse can actually cause a program to run slower. Inlining a very small accessor function will usually decrease code size while inlining a very large function can dramatically increase code size.

**Inlining in C#**

In C# inlining happens at the JIT level in which the JIT compiler makes the decision. There is currently no mechanism in C# which you can explicitly do this. If you wish to know what the JIT compiler is doing then you can call: `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` at runtime. If the Method is inlined it will return the name of the caller instead.

In C# you cannot force a method to inline but you can force a method not to. If you really need access to a specific callstack and you need to remove inlining you can use: `MethodImplAttribute` with `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining`. In addition if a method is declared as virtual then it will also not be inlined by the JIT. The reason behind this is that the final target of the call is unknown.

[More on inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidnotario/jit-optimizations-inlining-i)

Comment: To be more correct, you don't "tell the compiler," you "make a suggestion to the compiler that it may or may not heed."

Comment: Starting from .NET 4 (I think) you can actually force inlining. The `MethodImplOptions` now has a `AggressiveInlining` value for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For definition and discussion of inlining, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132738/why-should-i-ever-use-inline-code).

In C# you don't need to instruct the compiler or run-time to inline because the run-time will do it automatically.

P.S. This answer is also correct for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Inlining is when instead of calling a particular function, the contents of the function are done directly at the call site.  The main reason for doing this is that it removes the overhead of calling a function by running the function contents at the callsite.

It is used as an optimization technique.  In the case of C#, it actually depends on the CLR JIT engine to do the work.  At runtime, when compiling a method, the JIT engine will use a heuristic to determine if a function inline is appropriate and will be an effictive optimization.  If so, an inline is performed.

Vance has a great article on what the JIT considers when inlining: http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx

There is no way to force an inline in C#.  The language does not support this construct.  Mainly because people are very poor judges of what should be optimized.  The JITer is a much better judge.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Eric Gunnerson

[inlining happens at the JIT level, and the JIT generally makes a decent decision](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64644.aspx)