# Unable to change readonly field with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, readonly

So, I've encountered a weird problem while fiddling around and learning reflection.
I'm attempting to change a private, readonly field, like seen below:

```
public class A 
{
    private static readonly int x;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A obj = new A();
    Type objType = typeof(A);

    Console.WriteLine(obj.X);

    FieldInfo objField = objType.GetField("x", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    objField.SetValue(null, 100);

    Console.WriteLine(obj.X);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If I run the program as it stands above, then 0 will be printed to console each time.
However, if I comment out the first print, then the second will write out the expected 100.

Anyone who can shed some light on what's going on here? Thanks!

EDIT: Strangly it seems to work in Visual Studio 2012, but not in 2010. As far as I've found, the settings are the same in both.

EDIT 2: Works when building with platform target x64, and not with x86. Guess the new question is: why is that?

EDIT 3: Compared the x64 and x86 versions in disassembly; there seems to be some inlining going on in the x86 version.

EDIT 4: Okey, *think* I've figured out what's happening, sort of. I don't think that the property in class A being inlined is the problem. I believe that when it's time to read the property the second time in the main method, the property call is optimized away (backing field should be readonly, value should be the same) and the old value is reused. That's my "theory" at least.

Comment: thats because the first time you print you are calling it assigning it its default value which is 0,and after that its always 0,if you comment out the first,then you are assigning the value 100 and then printing its value.

Comment: *Calling Marc Gravel, calling Marc Gravel*

Comment: Since the field is marked as `readonly` the JIT might be inlining the `X` getter.

Comment: @terrybozzio Yeah, seems logical, but according to what I've read on this site in other threads, you should be able to change even readonly fields by using reflection. Unless I've misunderstood something

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on my machine. That is, the code you presented actually *works as expected*. And just to prove I am not leading you down the garden path: http://i.imgur.com/ZR1U7vW.png

Comment: @ByteBlast Guess you're the chosen one :p

Comment: @ByteBlast Try a release build instead of a debug build. :) For me it works for a debug build and not for a release build.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Based on your comment on Romoku's answer, I already tried and the code still prints "0" and then "100" as expected.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Wrong result in both release and debug

Comment: Possibly not relevant, but why do you use a non-static property `X` to expose a **static** field `x`? Have you tested if marking the field `volatile` changes anything? I'm not sure it's relevant with just one thread, but some optimization might choose to read `x` "too early" because the readonlyness seems to indicate that it is OK. ***Edit:*** The compiler does not allow `volatile` together with `readonly`, so part of this comment is meaningless.

Comment: If you remove the _first_ line with `Console.WriteLine(obj.X);`, then the last `Console.WriteLine(obj.X);` gets it right, i.e. `100`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Long story, but mostly I'm just playing around with reflection at this point. I might use it later (after I'm certain it works) to emulate a per-type unique ID for components in my entity-component game engine project. Currently I'm using a Dictionary<Type, int> to get unique IDs for my component types, but with some fairly ugly hacks, I can make it into a property call instead, making it way faster. EDIT: And yeah, I know, I mentioned that in the first post.

Comment: If you change the type of the field and property to e.g. `string` (a reference type) or `System.Numerics.BigInteger` (a value type which holds a reference to an array instance), the "problem" goes away.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right. Peculiar

Answer (score 6):

The JIT is inlining the getter:

Use the [`MethodImplAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) on the getter to suggested the JIT to not inline the property. This will not prevent the value of `x` from getting inlined, but removing the `readonly` will produce the desired result.

```
public class A
{
    private static int x;

    public int X
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        get { return x; }
    }
}
```

Now the output will be:

```
0
100
```

See: [Does C# inline properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646779/does-c-sharp-inline-properties)

One simple workaround is to use the nullable integer (`int?`) value type.

```
public class A 
{
    private static readonly int? x;

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return x ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`x` will not get inlined since the CLR will need to check whether the value of `x` is a valid cast to `int`.

Comment: You can see different results when you compile a debug build instead of a release even after making that change. I feel sure that it must be *something* to do with the jitter, though.

Comment: I still get the same result; both with deriving from MarshalByRefObject and with the attribute.

Comment: Above code still reproduces the "problem" under the condition specified in the EDIT paragraphs of the question, so `NoInlining` in attribute of `get` accessor does not seem to be enough.

Comment: The static field is `readonly` so the JIT inlines the property call. The solution would be don't change a static field that is marked as `readonly` since there is no way to control the JIT behavior.