# C# class property definitions

Tags: c#

Will I create any problems if I make all my class properties structure members like the following code does?

```
    private struct Properties
    {
        public int p1;
        public int p2;
    }
    private Properties P;
    public int p1 { get { return P.p1; } set { P.p1 = value; } }
    public int p2 { get { return P.p2; } set { P.p2 = value; } }
```

I did the analogous thing in VB for years, but then speed was not important.  Now I am just getting started with C# on real time projects where speed matters.  Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: What is the supposed advantage to that extra layer even in VB?

Comment: `"Will I create any problems"` - Well, it makes the code more complex for no discernible reason.  Complex things are more likely to fail than simple things.

Comment: What you're suggesting is essentially what's going on when you use the shorthand.  You just don't see the instance variable (because you really don't need to.)  The only reasons I know to do it your way is if you either have to do some sort of computation during the get/set, or you need to do some sort of range validation.

Comment: [Inner-platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect)  couldnt think of the term earlier

Comment: You *might* manage to defeat the compiler's normal inlining of property access: [Field vs Property. Optimisation of performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9843094/1115360), although the compiler people have included a lot of clever optimisations. What were the results of your tests?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. The problem will be unnecessary code. You could just shorten your code like this, and it will still function the same:

```
public int p1 { get;set; }
public int p2 { get;set; }
```

If you wanted to set breakpoints on getter or setter, you could use a backing private field like so:

```
private int _p1;
public int P1
{
    get { return _p1; }
    set { _p1 = value; }
}

private int _p2;
public int P2
{
    get { return _p2; }
    set { _p2 = value; }
}
```

Comment: I did this for the sake of sanity. I had classes with hundreds of properties.  After a month I'd have to add more in.  Using structures let me logically group them.  I made a code generator with a properties table.   I'd add properties to structures then generate all the code including utility methods, like to clear all values in a group, or import field values from a table, etc.  Also, some property groups would be copied to other classes.  Execution speed was unimportant (end of day batch processing).  Coding ease was.  But it may all boil down to personality.  I tend to box an label a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think your approach will create any problems. Speed and memory are definitely not an issue if you have one small extra struct with your properties - unless you are running your program on some device with just 64K Ram or so but I assume you don't.
So for your question - if you know what you're doing and accessing the right struct variables, then your code will be just fine.

However, as mentioned above, your approach is far from best practice.
C# is a language that uses either Auto-Properties or Properties with underlying backing fields extensively and it is considered best practice and also best maintainable if you follow this structure.

Properties also have a lot of neat advantages - further information under this link:
[MSDN Property Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx)

So, in summary, your approach is not necessarily *wrong* or *slow*, it is simply not *best practice*. And because we encourage *best practice*, I'd encourage you to not use your approach.

Comment: The reasons I did this in VB were: