# Is it best practice to create a variable if accessing a property of an object more than once in a routine?

Tags: c#, .net

When I first began as a junior C# dev, I was always told during code reviews that if I was accessing an object's property more than once in a given scope then I should create a local variable within the routine as it was cheaper than having to retrieve it from the object. I never really questioned it as it came from more people I perceived to be quite knowledgeable at the time.

Below is a rudimentary example

Example 1: storing an objects identifer in a local variable

```
public void DoWork(MyDataType object) 
{
    long id = object.Id;

    if (ObjectLookup.TryAdd(id, object))
    {
        DoSomeOtherWork(id);
    }

}
```

Example 2: retrieving the identifier from the Id property of the object property anytime it is needed

```
public void DoWork(MyDataType object) 
{
    if (ObjectLookup.TryAdd(object.Id, object))
    {
        DoSomeOtherWork(object.Id);
    }   
}
```

Does it actually matter or was it more a preference of coding style where I was working? Or perhaps a situational design time choice for the developer to make?

Comment: public Class MyDataType 
{
    publig int id {
        get {
            // Some actual code
            return this.GetHashCode() * 2;
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843264/4406995), if the property is a basic getter/setter than the CLR "will inline the property access and generate code that’s as efficient as accessing a field directly". However, if your property, for example, does some calculations every time the property is accessed, then storing the value of the property in a local variable will avoid the overhead of additional calculations being done.

Answer (score 5):

All the memory allocation stuff aside, there is the principle of DRY(don't repeat yourself). When you can deal with one variable with a short name rather than repeating the object nesting to access the external property, why not do that?

Apart from that, by creating that local variable you are respecting the single responsibility principle by isolating the methods from the external entity they don't need to know about.

And lastly if the so-called resuing leads to unwanted instantiation of reference types or any repetitive calculation, then it is a must to create the local var and reuse it throughout the class/method.

Any way you look at it, this practice helps with readability and more maintainable code, and possibly safer too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is faster or not (though I would say that the difference is negligible and thus unimportant), but I'll cook up some benchmark for you.

What IS important though will be made evident to you with an example;

```
public Class MyDataType 
{
    publig int id {
        get {
            // Some actual code
            return this.GetHashCode() * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Does this make more sense? The first time I will access the id Getter, some code will be executed. The second time, the same code will be executed costing twice as much with no need.

It is very probable, that the reviewers had some such case in mind and instead of going into every single one property and check what you are doing and if it is safe to access, they created a new rule.

Another reason to store, would be useability.

Imagine the following example

```
  object.subObject.someOtherSubObject.id
```

In this case I ask in reviews to store to a variable even if they use it just once. That is because if this is used in a complicated if statement, it will reduce the readability and maintainability of the code in the future.

Comment: If property returns different values every time you call it or executes some heavy lifting calculations or accessing external resources - that would be very big surprise for consumer of that class, so there is different problem then

Comment: Not different per se, the example above will always return the same id for the same object, but yes properties tend sometimes to have at least some minimal calculation (even if it was just a simple addition), which in a for loop would be a significan problem.

Answer (score 1):

A local variable is essentially guaranteed to be fast, whereas there is an unknown amount of overhead involved in accessing the property.

It's almost always a good idea to avoid repeating code whenever possible. Storing the value once means that there is only one thing to change if it needs changing, rather than two or more.

Using a variable allows you to provide a name, which gives you an opportunity to describe your intent.

I would also point out that if you're referring to other members of an object a lot in one place, that can often be a strong indication that the code you're writing actually belongs in that other type instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that getting a value from a method that is calculated from an I/O-bound or CPU-bound process can be irrational. Therefore, it's better to define a var and store the result to avoid multiple same processing.
In the case that you are using a value like `object.Id`, utilizing a variable decorated with `const` keyword guarantees that the value will not change in the scope.
Finally, it's better to use a local var in the classes and methods.